# Why number of partitions after joining two DStreams are changing

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-cluster")
                               .setAppName("SparkJob")
                               .set("spark.executor.memory","2G")
                               .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout","5")


val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Minutes(1))

var historyRdd: RDD[(String, ArrayList[String])] = streamingContext.sparkContext.emptyRDD

var historyRdd_2: RDD[(String, ArrayList[String])] = streamingContext.sparkContext.emptyRDD


val stream_1 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, GenericData.Record, StringDecoder, GenericDataRecordDecoder](streamingContext, kafkaParams ,  Set(inputTopic_1))
val dstream_2 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, GenericData.Record, StringDecoder, GenericDataRecordDecoder](streamingContext, kafkaParams ,  Set(inputTopic_2))


val dstream_2 = stream_2.map((r: Tuple2[String, GenericData.Record]) => 
{
  //some mapping
}

val historyDStream = dstream_1.transform(rdd => rdd.union(historyRdd))
dstream_2.foreachRDD(r => r.repartition(500))
val historyDStream_2 = dstream_2.transform(rdd => rdd.union(historyRdd_2))
val fullJoinResult = historyDStream.fullOuterJoin(historyDStream_2)

 val filtered = fullJoinResult.filter(r => r._2._1.isEmpty)


filtered.foreachRDD{rdd =>

  val formatted = rdd.map(r  => (r._1 , r._2._2.get)) 

  historyRdd_2.unpersist(false) // unpersist the 'old' history RDD
  historyRdd_2 = formatted // assign the new history
  historyRdd_2.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) // cache the computation
}


val filteredStream = fullJoinResult.filter(r => r._2._2.isEmpty)


filteredStream.foreachRDD{rdd =>
  val formatted = rdd.map(r => (r._1 , r._2._1.get)) 
  historyRdd.unpersist(false) // unpersist the 'old' history RDD
  historyRdd = formatted // assign the new history
  historyRdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) // cache the computation
}
streamingContext.start()
streamingContext.awaitTermination()
 }
}
```

Here my stream_1 and dstream_2 have 128 partitions but when I am doing the join the partitions are getting decreased to 3 partitions, why is it so. As I know, join is done partition wise i.e. partition 1 will join with partition 1 of another Rdd. All the filtered RDDs have 3 partitions that's why historyRDD and HistoryRDD2 has 3 partitions.

Answer (score 0):

partition in spark is depends on what operation you perform. for example `groupByKey()` retains the partition numbers of its parent RDDs if any.On the contrary , some operations like `join()` *sums up the number of partitions from both RDD1 and RDD2*. Assume if RDD1 has 2 partitions and RDD2 has 3 partitions then outcome of join() would be 5.

Comment: Then can you tell why partitions are decreasing, join of historyDStream_1(128 partitions) and historyDStream_2(128 partitions) , so according to your logic it should be 256 but it is 3.